# Fragile's umbrella?

Tags: death-stranding

Is it Higgs who makes Fragile teletransport?
If it is Fragile's umbrella which makes her teletransport then why doesn't her umbrella vanish with her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragile has the inherent ability to jump via Beaches and uses the "umbrella" as a navigational aid as per [this interview](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Fragile%27s_Umbrella_and_Suit):

> You think that thing Fragile carries is an umbrella? I can see why you'd jump to that conclusion, what with the shape and all, but you're wrong. If it's any consolation, I thought it was an umbrella, too, at first. It's actually some kind of navigational device that Fragile came up with herself. I won't pretend to understand the theory behind it, but I'm told it factors chiral density across Beaches and plots coordinates for her jumps.
>
> Fragile's got some kind of DOOMS that lets her move from Beach to Beach. The way she tells it, she kind of clears her mind and lets her powers do the rest. Maybe it's something similar with the spikes on her suit? When Fragile senses chiralium concentrations, they pop out. I'm not sure if she'd be able to tell otherwise. It's like an unconscious reaction—the spikes only retract when chiral density decreases.
>
> But who knows. Names and theories are just ways of coping with things we don't really understand. Same with visual indications of the intangible, maybe. All I can say is that Fragile's umbrella and spikes seem to help her hone her powers.
>
> I mean it is an umbrella though, it keeps the timefall rain off her face...

Based on the video, and comments online, it seems the general understanding of that scene is that Higgs uses his telekinesis to knock the device from Fragile's hands, and she chooses to teleport anyway. Presumably, she can still teleport without it, just not as accurately, so depriving her of it will keep her occupied for longer.

The umbrella, of course, [is able to be gifted in-game to the player to enable a Fast Travel system](https://hearthstats.net/how-to-unlock-death-stranding-fragile-jump-fast-travel/).